# Do I need to add Flutter and Dart license into the app?

Tags: licensing

I'm currently programming an app with flutter and have already listed all the licenses I use from the packages on an individual license page in the Settings. The question I am now asking myself is do I have to add the license for Flutter and Dart too to this list?

Here is the link to the darts license: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/engine/master/sky/packages/sky_engine/LICENSE

Here is the link to the flutter license: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/LICENSE

Here is the link to the page where I found the information: https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#which-software-licenses-apply-to-flutter-and-its-dependencies

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate): https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/11830/do-i-need-to-add-flutter-and-dart-license-into-the-app

Answer (score -1):

No, as far as i know, you don't need to explicitly add these licenses.
But if you want **to be 100%** safe i would just add them as it's not that much work for you to do.

Comment: Do you have any reason (links) why you think so?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Answer should be assured. If you want to give an advice (not an answer) or you don't actually sure about the answer just write a comment. Comments will be available as soon as you gain little more reputation.

Comment: @Mol0ko alright thanks for pointing this out!
No but neither Flutter nor Dart specify anything regarding licenses. Maybe just add this here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/LICENSE . This should be the only one you need regarding Flutter itself. If its really needed i cant say but adding it should not be the problem.